# Trigger build on specific branch merges to master

Tags: git, teamcity

I am trying to find a way to trigger a build on the master branch when a specific branch is merged into it.

I am adopting a `git-flow` approach, and one of the requirements is to trigger a release build job when a `hotfix` branch is merged to the `master` branch.

I tried the following settings on Teamcity:

**VCS Settings:**

1. Default branch: `refs/heads/master`
2. Branch Specification: `+:refs/heads/hotfix*`

**Trigger Settings:**

1. Trigger: VCS Trigger
2. Parameter, VCS trigger rules: +:hotfix*

The problem is that *any* branch which is merged to `master` is able to trigger the build. I only want to restrict the build to be only triggered on `hotfix` merges only.

Is this even possible on Teamcity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open the `Branch specification:` and add +:refs/heads/*

Open the build and add  VCS Trigger with parameters

```
+:hotfix*
-:*
```

so, you included the hotfix branches and excluded other.